# Losing double precision when dealing with timestamps

Tags: objective-c, swift, iso8601

I have a simple `XCTestCase`:

```
func testExample() {
    let date = "2015-09-21T20:38:54.379912Z";// as NSString;
    let date1 = 1442867934.379912;

    XCTAssertEqual(date1, NSDate.sam_dateFromISO8601String(date).timeIntervalSince1970);
}
```

This test passes, when it shouldn't, for two reasons:

- `1442867934.379912` becomes `1442867934.379911` in the test, even though its literally just a variable re-printed
- the `sam_` function (copied below) seems to think the same way, the `millisecond` variable becomes `millisecond  double  0.37991200000000003 0.37991200000000003` which when later converted from `NSDate` to `double`, seems to lose the microsecond precision (debugger):
  `po NSDate.sam_dateFromISO8601String(date).timeIntervalSince1970  -> 1442867934.37991`

`po 1442867934.379912 -> 1442867934.37991`

Any idea why? The microsecond precision (6 decimal places) is really important to my application, I need to seamlessly convert to and from `NSString` and `NSDate` using the `iso8601` format.

---

```
+ (NSDate *)sam_dateFromISO8601String:(NSString *)iso8601 {
    // Return nil if nil is given
    if (!iso8601 || [iso8601 isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Parse number
    if ([iso8601 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[(NSNumber *)iso8601 doubleValue]];
    }

    // Parse string
    else if ([iso8601 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        const char *str = [iso8601 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        if (len == 0) {
            return nil;
        }

        struct tm tm;
        char newStr[25] = "";
        BOOL hasTimezone = NO;

        // 2014-03-30T09:13:00Z
        if (len == 20 && str[len - 1] == 'Z') {
            strncpy(newStr, str, len - 1);
        }

        // 2014-03-30T09:13:00-07:00
        else if (len == 25 && str[22] == ':') {
            strncpy(newStr, str, 19);
            hasTimezone = YES;
        }

        // 2014-03-30T09:13:00.000Z
        else if (len == 24 && str[len - 1] == 'Z') {
            strncpy(newStr, str, 19);
        }
        // 2014-03-30T09:13:00.000000Z
        else if (len == 27 && str[len - 1] == 'Z') {
            strncpy(newStr, str, 19);
        }


        // 2014-03-30T09:13:00.000-07:00
        else if (len == 29 && str[26] == ':') {
            strncpy(newStr, str, 19);
            hasTimezone = YES;
        }

        // Poorly formatted timezone
        else {
            strncpy(newStr, str, len > 24 ? 24 : len);
        }

        // Timezone
        size_t l = strlen(newStr);
        if (hasTimezone) {
            strncpy(newStr + l, str + len - 6, 3);
            strncpy(newStr + l + 3, str + len - 2, 2);
        } else {
            strncpy(newStr + l, "+0000", 5);
        }

        // Add null terminator
        newStr[sizeof(newStr) - 1] = 0;

        if (strptime(newStr, "%FT%T%z", &tm) == NULL) {
            return nil;
        }

        double millisecond = 0.0f;

        NSString *subStr = [[iso8601 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."].lastObject substringToIndex:6];

        millisecond = subStr.doubleValue/1000000.f;

        time_t t;
        t = mktime(&tm);

        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:t + millisecond];
    }

    NSAssert1(NO, @"Failed to parse date: %@", iso8601);
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply changing my API to pass `double` representation of a `Time` object. i.e. `1442867934.379912`not messing with `ISO8601` at all.

`NSDate` supports this natively. So I don't have to parse any strings. Therefore, performance is an added bonus.

A couple quirks I encountered while doing this in Rails/Rabl/Oj:

- Need to send the `double` as a `string`. It seems the `JSONKit` on iOS doesn't like more than 15 significant digits, and neither does the `JSON` spec.

Rabl (initializer):

```
Oj.default_options = {
  use_to_json: true,
  second_precision: 6,
  float_precision: 16
}
```

The default `to_f` was not sending the precision I needed.

Answer (score 0):

`1442867934.379912` and `1442867934.379911` may very well equal the same number just printed differently (one rounded, the other truncated)... if microsecond time is important to you, perhaps you should look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html

especially because [NSDate date] can change wildly when the clock changes... and an absolute time api will not...

Comment: I never let the client modify or create any timestamps. Everything is coming from the server and being passed back to determine which objects need syncing. I'm not sure how that article can help me... I think if I did this over again I would send the timestamps as a number and store as an NSNumber on the client... but given my desire to use NSDate, how can I parse the microseconds to and from NSString and NSDate? It's really just simple inputs and outputs ... just not proving to be very simple.